# JPA LockModeType without version field

Tags: java, jpa, versioning

As I understand, JPA 1.0 `LockModeType.write` works with field annotated `@Version`.

This field is incremented each time, when entity is read or written. But how JPA works when this field is absent?

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/hibernate/hibernate-core/src/matrix/java/org/hibernate/test/jpa/lock/JPALockTest.java.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Field Locking`. When using field locking fields are compared when updating.

Take a look at [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking).

Answer (score 0):

Lock mode only applies to entities configured with an @Version.  It will either throw an error, or have no affect without a version.

JPA 2 also defines pessimistic locking, and some JPA providers provide other forms of locking.